# ASP.NET MVC HtmlHelper.ActionLink replace %20 with +

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If I have a url generated like this

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Link name", "MyAction", "MyController", new { SomeParameter = "value with spaces" })%>
```

is it possible to easily generate the output html like so

```
<a href="/MyController/MyAction/value+with+spaces">
```

instead of

```
<a href="/MyController/MyAction/value%20with%20spaces">
```

Or am I best looking at overloading the ActionLink method and replacing those characters when returning the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Or am I best looking at overloading
>   the ActionLink method and replacing
>   those characters when returning the
>   string?

Yes.

The easier way is to just make a space-dash replacer extension method.  Or just call Replace manually.

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Link name", "MyAction", "MyController", new { SomeParameter = "value with spaces".Replace(" ", "-" })%>
```

Comment: You are missing a bracket for Replace, don't you think ? .....BTW thanks, it saved me a lot of time :-)